# Enable TCP keepalive on port open by another program

Tags: tcp-keepalive

On a Debian machine I'm using an OPCUA server https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio. The server does not give the possibility to enable TCP keepalive on the port opened by the server.

Basically, I want to know if it's possible to start the server then in another script, enable the tcp keepalive on that port.

I also found some other information from Redhat https://access.redhat.com/solutions/19029, and https://access.redhat.com/solutions/25773 (requires you to sign up to see the articles). But again I'm still lost as to what to do exactly.

I'll keep reading up on this, but so far I've spent about 10 hours trying to figure out whether it's even possible. So I thought I should ask for some help.

Any advice is welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For operations of socket of another process socket must be shared from it https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.share or duplicated.

Its easier to patch your server for keepalive.